# Flutter: Task 'assembleStageDebug' not found in root project 'android'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I was trying my app which is made on flutter on an android device and when I tried running the app on my mobile, I am getting the following error
"Task 'assembleStageDebug' not found in root project 'android'.  "

my app works well on iOS but when running it on android, it is causing the problem. The flutter doctor detected no issues and no one seems to have the same problem as I do. I was first facing the problem of " Unsuported Android Plugin version: 4.0.1.". I was told to add a flavor by going to run -> edit config -> flavors and added the name to the flavor and ran the app using flutter run --flavor "flavor_name" which resulted in this error. Thanks in advance!

Error Message

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Task 'assembleStageDebug' not found in root project 'android'.          
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 1s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'assembleStageDebug'...                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleStageDebug'... Done                    2.4s

[!]  Gradle project does not define a task suitable for the requested build.
The android/app/build.gradle file does not define any custom product flavors. You cannot use the --flavor option.
Gradle task assembleStageDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Flutter Doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at /Users/apple/Documents/flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (7 months ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • A1601             • HMG6NJZPTCWWNRJJ                     • android-arm64 • Android 5.1 (API 22)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max • BC0BB924-53E6-4FEB-98BD-7873F1B272A3 • ios           • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties =  new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw  GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.enigma.vibing"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}


rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I had faced this same problem before. I did flutter upgrade and it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 9):

The issue is because you have not mentioned the `flavorDimensions` in `android/app/build.gradle/`

I hope you have created the `flavor` properly for your project. If not, then read this article and  [set up your flavor](https://blog.codemagic.io/environments-in-flutter-with-codemagic-cicd/).

After setting up your `flavor`, you need to add this code into your `android/app/build.gradle/` in the `android` section.

```
flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "default"
            versionNameSuffix "--dev"
        }
        stage {
            dimension "default"
            versionNameSuffix "--stage"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "default"
        }
    }
```

Use this as your code

```
def localProperties =  new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw  GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.enigma.vibing"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    //Add this code for flavor
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "default"
            versionNameSuffix "--dev"
        }
        stage {
            dimension "default"
            versionNameSuffix "--stage"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "default"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Run `flutter clean` and re-run the app and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

the problem for me was that i didn't had settings.gradle under root project so, add that file under root project and add this line in it

```
include ':app'
```

hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Using android studio to run flutter try going to your project structure and change project SDK to Android API 27 Platform then apply and re-run the app

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`flutter upgrade`

then

`flutter run -v`

This will help you

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

I cloned a Flutter project from my git remote repository to run on a different machine.

Some required files for an Android build were not committed to repository.

Android builds would fail with:

```
task 'assembledebug' not found in root project 'android'
```

#### Solution

Inside the project directory, in a terminal (re-) run:

`flutter create .`

**What Happens**

This creates a couple key files if missing:

- `android/settings.gradle`
- `android/gradle.properties`

The output will be similar:

```
$ flutter create .

Recreating project ....
  your_project.iml (created)
  .metadata (created)
  android/gradle.properties (created)
  android/.gitignore (created)
  android/settings.gradle (created)
  android/your_project_android.iml (created)
  .idea/runConfigurations/main_dart.xml (created)
  .idea/libraries/KotlinJavaRuntime.xml (created)
Wrote 11 files.
```

**Why this works**

`gradle.properties` is important for Android app SDK levels beyond 28 which [replaces the old Android Support Libraries with AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx):

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

`settings.gradle` is important for its including of `:app` and setting the Flutter SDK location:

```
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

After these two files in are in place, Android builds should complete properly.

Answer (score 0):

**THIS FIX WORKED FOR ME**

We have to add `flavorDimensions` and other lines after `buildTypes`.

I was adding `falvorDimensions` inside `buildTypes` so it was giving me the error and once I removed the flavor config from `buildTypes` and moved it right after the closing `}` bracket, it started working.

These are flavor config I used (Remember after closing `}` of buildTypes):

```
buildTypes {
} // TODO: After this, add productFlavors

productFlavors {
    production {
        dimension "default"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "APP_NAME"
        applicationIdSuffix ""
    }
    staging {
        dimension "default"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Stg APP_NAME"
        applicationIdSuffix ".stg"
    }
    development {
        dimension "default"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Dev APP_NAME"
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }
}
```

**Just an extra point:**
Depending on the IDE that you are using, configure the different flavor builds in specific files to avoid using the command every time.